# Union Query of Date Fields in MS Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have entries in a data table *TableofDates* comprising three fields; ProjectID (type = dbText), Start (type = dbDate) and Finish (type = dbDate):

**TableofDates**

```
ProjectID   Start       Finish  
ABC         01/01/2018  09/09/2018
```

I wish to present the following dataset with individual DateA records (derived from [Start] in [TableofDates]) and DateB records (derived form [Finish] in [TableofDates])

**ToD UNION**

```
ProjectID   DateA       DateB
ABC         01/01/2018  
ABC                     09/09/2018
```

The following SQL Query produces almost the result required:

```
SELECT ProjectID,DateA, '' AS DateB
FROM DtA
UNION SELECT ProjectID, '' AS DateA,DateB
FROM DtB;
```

The problem I have is that the inserted null strings force the field data to type dbText.

If instead I insert Nulls, I get only the first date field reproduced:

```
SELECT ProjectID, DateA, Null AS DateB 
FROM DtA 
UNION SELECT ProjectID, Null AS DateA, DateB 
FROM DtB;
```

yields:

```
ToD UNION
ProjectID   DateA       DateB
ABC         01/01/2018  
ABC
```

Both parts of the Union work individually:

```
SELECT ProjectID,DateA, Null AS DateB
FROM DtA;
```

yields

```
ToD UNION
ProjectID   DateA        DateB
ABC         01/01/2018
```

While

```
SELECT ProjectID,Null AS DateA,  DateB
FROM DtB;
```

Yields

```
ToD UNION
ProjectID   DateA       DateB
ABC                     09/09/2018
```

Any ideas how I can create a union of TableofDates with inserted "Null" dates as required, and maintain Data Type of dbDate in the resultant dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a header row (a select statement that returns 0 records, but includes the correct types and labels)

```
SELECT CLng(1) As ProjectID, #2001-01-01# As DateA, #2001-01-01# As DateB
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE 1=0
UNION ALL
SELECT ProjectID, DateA, Null 
FROM DtA 
UNION ALL
SELECT ProjectID, Null, DateB 
FROM DtB;
```

Your query doesn't work, because in Access, the first query of a union query determines the type and label of the field. Because the last column of the first query only contains `Null`, Access can't determine a field type, and chooses the wrong one.

By using a query that doesn't return records, but sets the field type explicitly, you're avoiding that problem.

Note that the change from `UNION` (which typecasts and checks for duplicates) to `UNION ALL` (which doesn't do those things) also fixes the problem. So 2 solutions for the price of one.

Comment: Sir, thank you that worked beautifully.  However, I don't understand why my query did not work.  Do you have any idea?

SELECT ProjectID, DateA, Null AS DateB 
FROM DtA 
UNION SELECT ProjectID, Null AS DateA, DateB 
FROM DtB;

Answer (score 0):

A Union query will ignore field alias names except for those in the first SELECT statement.

A NULL value is less than any date value, so a descending sort will place the NULLS first.

This SQL produces your example output:

```
SELECT              ProjectID, Start AS DateA, NULL AS DateB
FROM                TableOfDates

UNION ALL SELECT    ProjectID, NULL, Finish
FROM                TableOfDates
ORDER BY            ProjectID, DateA DESC
```

This table:

```
ProjectID   Start       Finish  
ABC         01/01/2018  09/09/2018  
DEF         01/02/2017  03/05/2018
```

Produced this result:

```
ProjectID   DateA       DateB  
ABC         01/01/2018    
ABC                     09/09/2018  
DEF         01/02/2017  
DEF                     03/05/2018
```